# Inventory management app suitable for home use, based around physical boxes

Tags: inventory, knowledge-organization

I'm looking for some kind of application that would allow me to organize a large number of opaque storage totes that contain various items. This is almost a warehouse-style model, but it's for home or storage unit use.

One of the issues I see with the business inventory/home inventory apps I've seen is that they want you to enter a lot of details about each *individual item*. I'm not interested in this - my ideal app is concerned primarily with the storage containers, with the contents tracked as a nothing more complicated than a quantity and a description.

An example set of records would look like:

```
Boxes:
+---------------+--------+--------------------------+
|   Box name    | Box ID |           Tags           |
+---------------+--------+--------------------------+
| PC Stuff 1    |  00001 | PC parts, power supplies |
| Music stuff 1 |  00002 | Patch cables             |
+---------------+--------+--------------------------+

Items:
+--------+----------+----------------------------+
| Box ID | Quantity |        Description         |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+
|  00001 |        2 | 600W Modular PSU           |
|  00001 |        1 | 4Pin CPU power connector   |
|  00001 |        2 | 8pin PIC power connector   |
+--------+----------+----------------------------+
```

Requirements:

- Based around boxes or item containers
- **Doesn't require entering detailed information about individual items in each box.** Ideally, only a quantity and a description would be necessary. This eliminates most business-tier apps as far as I can tell.
- Boxes could be given searchable tags
- Allows for rapid entry (i.e. on a phone while I sort items into boxes)
- Allows for either generation of barcode labels, or supports entering barcode values to be associated with each box (and then I can print labels separately)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few android apps, that can help you with this e.g.

- [Magic Home Inventory](https://apkpure.com/magic-home-inventory/net.twisterrob.inventory) - it enables boxes to be created using lists, which can then contain other items (Lists)
- Also have a look at [Sortly](https://apkpure.com/sortly-inventory-simplified/com.sortly.mythings). You can probably use categories or folders to mimic Boxes. It enables barcode scanning, but not sure if it can do generation.

You will find a few others on apkpure.com, but you will have to try out to see if they meet all your requirements.